# Function<String, Consumer<String>> java 8

Tags: java, lambda

What does this below lambda function do?

```
public class FunctionInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<String, Consumer<Integer>> secondFunction = s -> x -> System.out.println(x);

        System.out.println(secondFunction.apply("Text"));
    }
}
```

The above code is printing some random value, how to make it print text?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: This `Function` returns `Consumer<Integer>`. To print something, you need to do `secondFunction.apply("").accept(10)`

Comment: Why are you writing code that you don't understand and then wonder why it doesn't do what you want? Just do `Consumer<String> consumer  = x -> System.out.println(x); consumer.accept("Text");` - why do you need a function that returns a consumer given a string parameter that you're not using at all?

Comment: or simply `System.out::println` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `secondFunction` is a `Function` that takes a `String` and returns a `Consumer<Integer>`. In this line:

```
System.out.println(secondFunction.apply("Text"));
```

you are calling `apply` on the `Function`, which will return a `Consumer<Integer>`, and then you print the object, which will cause `toString` to be called on the `Consumer<Integer>` object (and then the string will be printed).

It will not run the lambda expression, which is what you seem to expect. Try this instead:

```
// Call accept(123) on the consumer, which will execute the lambda
secondFunction.apply("Text").accept(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you wanted to print "Text" maybe this is easier?
You don't need to return the consumer with a Function. I'm confused what is the purpose?

```
Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
consumer.accept("Text");
```

Comment: I was experimenting with lambdas :)